# How to automate mysql copy database?

Tags: mysql, wamp

I have a WAMP server with 2 mySQL databases :

One Database for exploitation, and a second database for reporting.
The reporting database is a copy of the exploitation database.

Actually, the copy is done manually with phpmyAdmin : I export the exploitation database, then, i import it in the "Reporting database".

I would like to automate this task.

The server is on Windows with WAMP.

I was thinking a about doing this with a .bat and using the Windows Task Scheduler but i don't really know how automate the export and import database.

Anyone can help me please ?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: what is the reason for this? can't you use the same db for reporting also? Reporting shouldn't modify any data... anyway you should create a php file that performs the copy and then schedule a cron job to run that php file

Comment: I want a copy ;)  Anyway to do it with any program ?

Comment: I gave you the solution in my comment

Answer (score 0):

For the requirement that you have mentioned, it is assumed that both the databases have the same schema. That being said, usually the best way to achieve real-time replication is Master Slave database setup. You should read more about it in below link:

https://www.toptal.com/mysql/mysql-master-slave-replication-tutorial

If you still want to use a batch file for replication, provided both databases exist on the same server, you can write below commands in the batch script:

```
//Export database to SQL file
mysqldump -u [username] -p [sourceDatabase] > [filename]-$(date +%F).sql

//Import database from SQL file
mysql -u [username] -p [targetDatabase] < [filename]-$(date +%F).sql
```

You can then schedule this script in off-peak hours to prevent any slow downs or database locking.